# Getting a page with a headless browser returns a response different from a normal one

Tags: javascript, python

When I go to https://soundcloud.com using either Firefox or Chrome, the normal front page is displayed. However, when I use either ghost.py or Robobrowser (the only two Python headless browsers I found which support Javascript and work with Python 3) with all cookies directly copied from Chrome request (including useragent), the grabbed page says 'we cannot find this page' (with fully formed interface, not just a 404 error). I know that Javascript is executed, since trying to visit the site without it enabled gives a specific message about needing to use a browser supporting it. Specifically, here are the headers I'm attaching (though not doing so doesn't change the result):

```
headers = {
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
'Referer':'https//soundcloud.com/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1'
}
```

I checked every similar question on SO and they all boil down to either incorrect headers or browser not supporting Javascript, neither of which applies here.

Comment: Does selenium and phantomjs not work? seems to pull the correct source for me

Comment: If that fully formed 404 page is generated by JS, then that missing resource must have been requested dynamically. What's the request and response look like for other requests on that page? You can use a debugging proxy like Charles to check what other stuff is happening.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python implementation of PhantomJS (PyPhantomJS) doesn't support Python 3 and I, uh, can't get Selenium to work at all.

Comment: Phantomjs does work with selenium using python3

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Soundcloud can only be connected to over HTTPS, so I'm not getting anything through Charles other than a request to and response from the root URL.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep, it worked and returned the same JS'd 404 page as the other browsers.